# Changing printing format for fractions using sympy and PythonTex

Tags: python-3.x, latex, sympy, fractions

Below is a minimal working problem, of what I am working on.
The file is a standard LaTeX file using `sympy` within `pythontex`, where I want to change
how `sympy` displays fractions.

Concretely I would like to make the following changes, but have been struggling:

- How can I make sympy display the full, and not inline version of it's fractions for *some* of its fractions? In particular I would like the last fraction `1/5` to instead be displayed in full.
  eg. `\fraction{1}{5}`
- In the expression for the derivative, I have simplified the results, but I struggle to substitute the variable `x` with the fraction `a/b`. Whenever I substitute this expression into the fraction it fully simplifies the expression, which is not what I want. I just want to replace `x` with the fraction `a/b` (in this case `2/3` or `1/3` depending on the seed).

Below I have attached two images displaying what my code produces, and what I would like it to display. Do note that this is also stated in the two bullets above

### Current output

[image]

### Desired output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
import math
from sympy import *
from random import randint, seed

seed(2021)
\end{pycode}

\paragraph{Oppgave 3}

\begin{pycode}
a, b = randint(1,2), 3
ab = Rational(a,b)

pressure_num = lambda x: 1-x
pressure_denom = lambda x: 1+x

def pressure(x):
  return (1-x)/(1+x)

pressure_ab = Rational(pressure_num(ab),pressure_denom(ab))

x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
pressure_derivative = simplify(diff(pressure(x), x))
pressure_derivative_ab = pressure_derivative.xreplace({ x : Rational(a,b)}) 
\end{pycode}

The partial pressure of some reaction is given as
%
\begin{pycode}
print(r"\begin{align*}")
print(r"\rho(\zeta)")
print(r"=")
print(latex(pressure(Symbol('\zeta'))))
print(r"\qquad \text{for} \ 0 \leq \zeta \leq 1.")
print(r"\end{align*}")
\end{pycode}
%
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
    \item Evaluate $\rho(\py{a}/\py{b})$. Give a physical interpretation of your
        answer.
    \begin{equation*}
        \rho(\py{a}/\py{b})
        = \frac{1-(\py{ab})}{1+\py{ab}}
        = \frac{\py{pressure_num(ab)}}{\py{pressure_denom(ab)}}
        \cdot \frac{\py{b}}{\py{b}}
        = \py{pressure_ab}
    \end{equation*}
\end{enumerate}

The derivative is given as
%
\begin{pycode}
print(r"\begin{align*}")
print(r"\rho'({})".format(ab))
print(r"=")
print(latex(pressure_derivative))
print(r"=")
print(latex(simplify(pressure_derivative_ab)))
print(r"\end{align*}")
\end{pycode}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever I substitute this expression into the fraction it fully simplifies the expression, which is not what I want. I just want to replace x with the fraction `a/b` (in this case `2/3` or `1/3` depending on the seed).

It's possible to do this, if we use a `with` expression to [temporarily disable evaluation](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12017#issuecomment-270311862) for that code block, and then we use [two dummy variables](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#dummy) in order to represent the fraction, and finally we do the substitution with numerical values.

So the following line in your code:

```py
pressure_derivative_ab = pressure_derivative.xreplace({ x : Rational(a,b)})
```

can be changed to:

```py
with evaluate(False):
    a1,b1=Dummy('a'),Dummy('b')
    pressure_derivative_ab = pressure_derivative.subs(x,a1/b1).subs({a1: a,b1: b})
```

The expressions `pressure_derivative` and `pressure_derivative_ab` after this are:

[image]

> How can I make sympy display the full, and not inline version of it's fractions for some of its fractions? In particular I would like the last fraction `1/5` to instead be displayed in full. eg. `\fraction{1}{5}`

For this, you only need to change this line:

```
        = \py{pressure_ab}
```

into this line:

```
        = \py{latex(pressure_ab)}
```

Because we want pythontex to use the sympy [latex printer](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html#mathrm-latex), instead of the [ascii printer](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html#ascii-pretty-printer).

To summarize, the changes between the original code and the modified code can be [viewed here](https://github.com/wsdookadr/so/blob/master/so-66399441/p1.patch).

All the code in this post is [also available in this repo](https://github.com/wsdookadr/so/tree/master/so-66399441).

Comment: This looks great! Any idea how to figure out how to control when sympy writes a inline fraction a/b vs a full fraction?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I've just added a section about making `1/5` print as `\frac{1}{5}`